# Calculating variance of Discrete Uniform distribution when its interval changes

Tags: probability, statistics

> I am not excited about grading exams.  I would rather jam a dull stick into my leg.  I will therefore randomly assign your grade by picking an integer uniformly from 77 to 100 (inclusively).
>
> (a)  What is the probability that you score 80-89 inclusively?
>
> (b)  What is your expected score on the exam?
>
> (c)  What is the variance of scores on this exam?

$n=100-77+1=24$

(a)  There are 24 different grade possibilities and 10 scores between 80-89. So the solution is 10/24.

(b)  (c) I had a question.  There's a formula for discrete uniform:

$E[X]= \cfrac{(n+1)}{2}\tag{1}$

$Var[X]=\cfrac{n^2-1}{12}\tag{2}$

I thought both of these equations would only be valid if the grade assignments ranged from 1 to 100, inclusively.

Indeed Equation (1) cannot be used for part (b), but Equation (2) can be used for part (c).  **Why can equation (2) be used to calculate the variance when the grade range is only from 77-100.**  I rederived these formula's and in the derivation, I assumed $ X \ge 1$.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We answer the only specific question you asked. An important property of the variance is **shift-invariance**. Let $X$ be a random variable, and let $Y=X+k$ where $k$ is a constant. Then $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\operatorname{Var}(X)$. How much a random variable bounces around is not affected if you add say $300$ to each value.

So you can shift the grade range $77$ to $100$ downwards by $76$ without changing the variance.

Of course the mean does change, it goes down by $76$.